# Improper integral over an open set

Tags: analysis

I was checking Analysis on manifolds - Munkres about improper integrals and I found an interesting exercise that I'm not able to understand how to do it. It was about showing that the integral over the set B of $f(x)= 1 / (1+y)^2$ exist and the open set B was $$B = \left\{ (x,y) \mid  x > 0 \quad and \quad  x² < y < 2x² \right\}$$

Can you help me showing this existence I've benn thinking about it for several days now and I don't know how. Thaank you in advance.

Comment: Do you really mean what you've written? Is $f:\mathbb R_+\times\mathbb R_+\to \mathbb R$ with $f(x,y)=\frac1{(1+y)^2}$?

Answer (score 1):

This is straightforward and you don't even need estimates, it can be evaluated using Fubini and Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.
$$
\begin{split}
\iint_B & f(x,y) \, dx \, dy = \int_0^\infty \!\!\!\int_{x^2}^{2x^2} \frac{1}{(1+y)^2} \, dy \, dx
= \int_0^\infty \left[ -\frac{1}{1+y}\right]_{y=x^2}^{y=2x^2} \, dx \\
& = \int_0^\infty \left( -\frac{1}{1+x^2} + \frac{1}{1+2x^2} \right) \, dx
= \left[ -\arctan x + \frac{\arctan \left(\sqrt{2} x \right)}{\sqrt{2}}\right]_{x=0}^{x=\infty} \\
& =  \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}
\end{split}
$$